# User gets registered every time I refresh the page after submitting form

Tags: php, registration

I'm working on registration process with PHP. I managed to get submitted form data and save it into mysql table, but the problem is, if I refresh the page, user gets registered again. This is my PHP code which I have included in a div tag with other content:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["registration"])){
            $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "name") or die("connection error");
      if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

      $name = $_POST["name"];
      $lname = $_POST["lname"];
      $email = $_POST["email"];
      $pass = $_POST["pass"];
      $company = $_POST["company"];
      $webpage = $_POST["webpage"];
      $phone = $_POST["phone"];
      $country = $_POST["country"];
      $city = $_POST["city"];
      date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tbilisi');
      $info = getdate();
      $date = $info['mday'];
      $month = $info['mon'];
      $year = $info['year'];
      $hour = $info['hours'];
      $min = $info['minutes'];
      $sec = $info['seconds'];
      $reg_date = $year . "-" . $month . "-" . $date . " " . $hour . ":" . $min . ":" . $sec;
      $confirmed = "0";
      $success = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO users(firstname, lastname, email, pass, company, webpage, country, city, phone, reg_date, confirmed) VALUES('$name','$lname','$email', '$pass', '$company', '$webpage', '$country', '$city', '$phone', '$reg_date', '$confirmed')");
      if($success){
            echo "You have been successfully registered. Use the form above to log in.";
        }
        else{
            echo "registration error";
        }
      //unset($_POST["registration"]);
    }
  ?>
```

I've also tried to unset the `$_POST["registration"]` as you can see, but it did not help. What should I do, to make this code work only when the "register" button is clicked?

P.S. I'm starting session in the beginning of the page, but not assigning any data to it.

Comment: You are open to SQL injections you should parameterize your query. Set a session value when it gets processed, if present don't allow it to rerun.

Comment: The standard way of dealing with this is redirecting the user to another page after saving the data so that refreshing will refresh that page, not the processing page.

Comment: `unset($_POST["registration"]);` doesn't work because when the page is refreshed, the post data is resent to the server.

Comment: I know, I'm not checking input right now. I just need to fix the bug for now

Comment: that is the browser capability, whenever you refresh the page the same data is posted automatically by browser. Better after signup redirect user to another page not on same page

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: **Warning:** Do NOT use this code on a production site, you are saving plain text passwords and are at risk for SQL injection attacks.

Comment: _"I'm not checking input right now"_ <- it's more difficult to do later, trust me

Comment: @Devon I know, I'm planning to add input check for every field

Comment: @VaxoBasilidze neither password hashing or injection protection has to do with "input checks for each field"...

Comment: @user3783243 Here, I have covered my database from injection: $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["name"]); Did this to all inputs.

Comment: @Devon I have covered my database from injection: $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["name"]); Did this to all inputs.

Comment: That's not the right way to defend against injections.  Always use prepared statements, that method has been outdated for over 5 years.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: @Devon Ok, I'll take a look. I found an examples at w3schools, https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp I'll use this method then

Comment: Ok, be careful about what data you get from w3schools, I've seen a lot of outdated info on there over the years.  I'd recommend finding a teacher or professional mentor to guide you on best practices rather than trying to find your own information.  https://www.phptherightway.com/ is a pretty good site for best practices but I don't think they cover prepared statements.  Don't forget about password hashing either, read the section on that site and the duplicate I linked above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On success redirect the user to another url

```
header('Location: '. $url);
die();
```

Comment: What should I do if my project has single page?

Comment: The main goal is to clean the $ _POST variable, since a system variable can not be set, you have to do it implicitly. So you can also redirect the page to itself.

Comment: Will it work if I set to form action attribute: action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"

Comment: If it's a single page, consider using AJAX instead.

Comment: No, you need to make a new request to the server. To show a message like "Congratulations now you are registered!" you can add in the redirect url a query string and than check the variabile in the next request, or use a flag using $_SESSION (in both cases you have to clean the "state" variable).
Alternatively use ajax for the registration request (as suggested by @webnoob).